# ng-form nested within ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I ran into an issue with ng-form not setting up the form on scope when its nested within an ng-scope.

For example

```
<div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
    <ng-switch on="switchMe">
        <div ng-switch-default>Loading...</div>
        <div ng-switch-when="true">
            <form name="nixTest">
                <input placeholder='In switch' ng-model='dummy'></input>
                <button ng-click="test()">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </ng-switch>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
controllers.TestCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.switchMe = true;
    $scope.test = function () {

        if ($scope.nixTest) {
            alert('nixTest exists')
        } else {
            alert('nixTest DNE')
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any work arounds to this ?   Test fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/6cEAd/)

Comment: Of course the form is in the scope or you won't even trigger the test() function in the controller. Why you want the form on the scope then? What are you going to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-switch creates a child scope and the form is created on this scope. Hence the child scope form would not be available on the parent scope.

To get access to it, you can pass it to the method `test()` like `ng-click=test(nixTest)`. So the scope method signature would also need to updated to support the input parameter.

Comment: This is a really nasty work around, there has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: @Nix No need to criticize his solution. You should at least thank him for providing you with a working solution. Be civilized. And why you think there is a better way though since you can't propose any thing?

Comment: Since the form gets created in child scope the only workaround is this. At least there is one :) You can infact have these properties on model and then they are accessed without the form.

Comment: @Nix, at least he explained why form data is not accessible, and I think that's the most important part for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Unfortunately I could not easily apply [Chandermani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361151/chandermani)'s solution, because I need to access the form name from an `$on` call, within the `ng-switch` parent scope.
Thus, I resorted to creating a directive that sends the form's name to the `$rootScope`:

```
.directive("globalName", ["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
    return function(scope, element) {
        $rootScope["get_" + element.attr('name')] = function() {
            return scope[element.attr('name')];
        };
    }
}]);
```

Usage is like this:

```
<form name="whatever" novalidate global-name>...</form>
```

and then you access the form in controllers e.g. like this:

```
$scope.get_whatever().$setPristine();
$scope.get_whatever().$setUntouched();
```

Being the name in the `$rootScope`, it does not depend anymore on your DOM structure.

I understand this is not an optimal solution, as it pollutes the global namespace, but either I feel uncomfortable with form name visibility depending on the DOM structure, in somewhat unexpected ways.